# jquery Tablesorter scrolling not working bootstrap modal

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tablesorter

I am displaying table as jquery tablesorter in bootstrap modal. It's working fine sorting and all. But when adding scrolling widget the modal becomes blank, nothing displaying,

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    theme: 'ice',
    widthFixed: true,
    showProcessing: true,
    headerTemplate: '{content} {icon}',
    widgets: ['zebra', 'uitheme', 'scroller'],
    widgetOptions: {
        scroller_height: 300,
        scroller_barWidth: 17,
        scroller_jumpToHeader: true,
        scroller_idPrefix: 's_'
    }
});
```

Comment: What does this have to do with php?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add the table inside the `<div class="modal-body">`, then compare these two demos:

- [scroller widget in a Bootstrap modal](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/Leyaxm70/59/)

  ```
  $(function() {
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
      $('#table0').tablesorter({
        theme: 'bootstrap',
        headerTemplate: '{content} {icon}', // Add icon for various themes
        widgets: ['zebra', 'filter', 'uitheme', 'scroller'],
        widgetOptions: {
          scroller_height: 300
        }
      });
    });
  });
  ```
- [stickyHeaders widget in a Bootstrap modal](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/Leyaxm70/)

  CSS

  ```
  /* Bootstrap tweaks 
   adjust margin-top to accomodate for the Modal title block
   adjust margin-left to tweak positioning
  */
  .tablesorter-sticky-wrapper {
    margin-top: -87px;
    margin-left: -2px;
  }
  .modal-body {
    overflow-x: auto;
  }
  ```

  JS

  ```
  $(function() {
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
      $('#table0').tablesorter({
        theme: 'bootstrap',
        headerTemplate: '{content} {icon}', // Add icon for various themes
        widgets: ['zebra', 'filter', 'uitheme', 'stickyHeaders'],
        widgetOptions: {
          // jQuery selector or object to attach sticky header to
          stickyHeaders_attachTo: '#myModal',
          stickyHeaders_offset: 0,
          stickyHeaders_addCaption: true
        }
      });
      // make sure the stickyHeader isn't showing the second
      // time a modal is opened
      $('#myModal').scroll();
    });
  });
  ```