# MYSQL Table in Collapsed Accordion not Showing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tablesorter, bootstrap-accordion

I generate an HTML table from mysql DB using php (v7.1) and display it inside a boostrap (v3.3.7) accordion; in order to "play" with the table columns, I also use Tablesorter (v 2.30).

As long as I use the `collapse in` class, everything is OK, but if I want the table to be hidden by default and use the `collapse` class instead, when I click to expend it, the tab opens with the right size, but doesn't show any content. If I click F12 or F11, then the table content appears.

*HTML content*

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading1">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse1">
          <span style="color: black; font-size:10px"><strong>List all subscriotion forms <?php echo ( "(" . $TblSize . " volunteers)" ) ?></strong> (click to show/hide)</span>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading1">

        "...My php code to display the table content here... (see below)"

      <div class="panel-body">
      </div>
    </div>-->
  </div>-->
</div>-->
```

*TableSorter content* (actually generated using `echo (\t\t text \n);` in PHP section)

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#TblVolDet").tablesorter( {
      //defaults,
      theme: 'blue',
      saveSort: 'true',
      showProcessing: 'true',
      headerTemplate : '{content} {icon}',
      widgets: [ 'uitheme', 'zebra', 'scroller' ],
      widgetOptions: {
        filter_liveSearch: true,
        scroller_height: 500,
        scroller_jumpToHeader: true,
        scroller_upAfterSort: false,
        scroller_barWidth: null
      },
      dateFormat: "ddmmyyyy"
    });

    if ( $('.focus-highlight').length ) {
      $('.focus-highlight').find('td, th')
        .attr('tabindex', '1')
        // add touch device support
        .on('touchstart', function() {
        $(this).focus();
      });
    }

  });

</script>
```

Here comes the mysqli result (also using the `echo (...);` cmd)

```
      <table class="table table-responsive table-hover table-condensed tablesorter focus-highlight hover-highlight" id="TblVolDet" style="font-size:11px;" title="Shift + click to sort on several columns" width="100%"> <!-- Beginning of ''table class=''table table-responsive'''' -->
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Col1</th>
            <th>Col2</th>
            <th>Col3</th>
            <th>Col4</th>
            <th>Col5</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Text1</td>
            <td style='color: green; font-weight: bold;'>Text2</td>
            <td style='color: green; font-weight: bold;'>Text3</td>
            <td style='color: black; font-weight: normal;'>Text4</td>
            <td style='color: green; font-weight: bold;'>Text5</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: This sounds similar to using [tablesorter inside of a bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39013101/jquery-tablesorter-scrolling-not-working-bootstrap-modal/39030184#39030184)

Comment: Hi @Mottie, I was off for holidays. I will check your answer and come back to you asap. Thank you for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: I've tested your recommendation (@Mottie) and it works in the sense that the table is now visible. But I lose most of the tablesorter formatting; I just have the horizontal blue highlight that follows the mouse's position, no more sortable column headers, no more cell borders, no more blue cell background for the column header, etc.

Comment: I've also tested the solution from SimCam [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33258803/8888163)
`if($('tab_parent_of_the_table').is(':visible')) {
    $("your_table_table").tablesorter({
       widgets: ['zebra']
    });
}
`
Same result, the table now appears, but without most of the tablesorter features.

Comment: Please set up a demo (modify [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/bbxxomhx/)) to make it easier to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: I've setup a [Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Tanner_Alex/tm5vLscj/).
What I noticed is that when I add the "scroller" widget, the table stop showing.